# In Unity3D, remove all but a set amount of decimals from a number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a text display in Unity3D.  Wht would I do if I wanted to remove all but say 2 decimals from a float? To clarify what I want to do, please see the example below:

Say I have the floats:

1.25013

1.9012

1.029

Now, in Unity what should I do if I want to shorten them so only two decimals remain i.e returning 1.25, 1.90 and 1.02 before displaying the string such as on a `UI.Text` ?

I have looked into string formatting and stuff like `Math.Floor` without success.

Comment: What about `Math.Round( value, 2 )` ?

Comment: are you shortening them for display or do you want to actually trim those numbers?

Comment: *string formatting and stuff like math.floor without success*... what problem(s) did u face with these methods?

Comment: They are only for display, also im using unity in which Math.Round only takes one argument.

Comment: If it's only for display, then you should specify the rounding when you convert the number to a string for displaying: `string toBeDisplayed = number.ToString("f2");`

Comment: `string toBeDisplayed = number.ToString("F")` actually did the trick, thanks @MatthewWatson

Comment: hi @user6395724 - yes, Matthew's answer is the correct idiom in Unity.  Enjoy!

Comment: you shoudl probably put that in as an answer, @MatthewWatson since it's kind of canonical.  surprisingly not a dupe!

Comment: @JoeBlow It's ok, Scott's on the case. :)

Comment: wow thanks for the upvotes on the question, usually people say my questions are dumb and im bad at programming :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, if it is just for display the correct way to solve this problem is pass in a [numeric format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) to a `.ToString` call.

To get the format you described you would want the format string `f2`, that would create a fixed-point number with two decimal points that will look like `1234.50`

```
UI.Text = someNumber.ToString("f2");
```

If you would like a `,` in the number when you have more than 3 digits to the left of the decimal place like `1,234.50` use `n2` instead of `f2`

```
UI.Text = someNumber.ToString("n2");
```

Comment: what about another number of decimals? for 3 decimals, we do "number.ToString("f3")"?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to. Yes, if you want fixed 3 points with no comma it would be `"f3"`